# Where purchrase cheap MTB frame?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames

I recently bought a Merida HT matts sub 60, and I like it but sadly it's way to big for me, I purchrase it more for the components since it was really cheap. I'm 165cm, and probably need 16inch frame, and I kinda want to swap the frame (sadly the best part of the bike) with a more suitable one. I don't want to spend more than 100€, and I found some aluminum frame on Aliexpress for my budget, on ebay I found only quite expensive ones, and often on large size or with some cracks and other problems. I need a frame with disk brake mounts so it's hard to find a cheap bike just for the frame, for this reason I want to buy just the frame. Do you have any feedback about those cheap unknown chinese frame? Any other suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Buy a used bike.

Comment: buy the lowest model used bike in a lineup, often one with junk components that are used up.  throw the junk components away. salvage the frame.

Comment: Next time, try the bike before buying.  You could have bought a bike that fits you.

Comment: Well, I rode it, and noticed it was a little too big... but at that time I wanted a bike just to go around my town and with a ultra short stem I can use it. But since it was an MTB, I thought to use in some trails, since I never owned an MTB, and i really enjoyed it. As MTB sadly it not so usable by me, and I enjoyed so much I started to overhaul everything, even the cheap RST fork which works nicely now. And so I ended up with a nice functional bike, but not so confortable on trails, and for this I'm asking that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question is formulated now, there is no definitive answer. It is really up for you to decide. Here are some hints though.

You can either buy online, or in person. In both cases you can buy either new or used.

When buying online, you cannot "feel" an object before getting it, compared to buying in person. However, in both cases it is possible to see obvious problems if you are careful enough and you ask questions. For used frames that would be crash damage. For new frames it would be manufacturing/QA issues, such as poor welds.

You would not be able to tell "hidden" problems in either case, such as internal cracks or poor welds hidden behind coating, so there is always risk of getting something unusable. For used frames, there is rarely a possibility to claim warranty. For new frames, it depends, and usually the law is on your side as long as you have proof of purchase.

Remember that a bike frame is not a small object in its dimensions. When buying it from overseas or even ordering the delivery by post, freight costs are likely to eat a considerable part of your budget. When buying in person, this is something that can be avoided. But when buying in person, there is a small chance of ending up robbed and getting nothing (again, I do not know where you live and how bad the situation is there)

> I need a frame with disk brake mounts so it's hard to find a cheap bike just for the frame

Buying a bike just for the frame is almost always unwise when money is considered.

Comment: thank you for the wise answer. Sadly where I leave there is no so much bike culture (which might seems crazy since live in Italy), so people who sells used bikes usually overrate those, and you can make deals only when they don't know about the thing they are selling (happened only once in my life). Bike shops usually are not very kind with people who just want to buy bike parts without let them make the work for you, and sometimes even charge you more because of that. So I'm kinda stuck to buy things on the internet but really don't know which route I should take. thank you anyway.